# php include a web page containing some js into a div

Tags: php, html, include, shadowbox

I want to include in my web page another web page. I know how to do that.

```
<html>
<head>
<br>
<some links to external scripts...><br>
<br>
</head><br>
<body onload='$("#divkat").load("page1.php");'><br>
<div><br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="sidebar"><br>
              <h3>category :</h3><br>
         <a onclick='$("#divkat").load("page1.php");'>page1</a><br>
         <a onclick='$("#divkat").load("page2.php");'>page2</a><br>
         <a onclick='$("#divkat").load("page3.php");'>page3</a><br>
             <a onclick='$("#divkat").load("page2.php");'>page4</a><br>
           </div><br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="divkat"><br>< /div><br>
<  ! - - < ?php include( 'page1.php' ); ?>    - - ><br>
             < /div><br>
            < /div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</body><br>
</html>
```

it's working fine.

the problem is that the "page1.php" contain a few shadowbox (lightbox).
like this :

```
 <br>
< /div><br>
< div style="height:180px;width:180px;float:left;margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;"><br>
< a href="img/panorama-split.jpg" rel="shadowbox; height=500; width=960"><br>< img src="img/tumb-kastel.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="180" height="180" />< /a><br>
< div>
```

the main page won't run the JS. If I open the "pag1.php" it work normally.

I want to make a web gallery (main page containing categories) when I click on a category, 
php function include a page containing the items which open in a shadowbox.
One solution is to have many pages as categories, but is not piratical. To add a new 
category you must edit all of them. 
Someday maybe I'll program a admin interface for easy adding new category, pictures, and other media with links and thumbnails. Ofcorse  with possibility to delete and backup.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have here is that you are using HTML comments:

```
<  ! - -
```

This means that when PHP includes the HTML in `page1.php` it will actually be commented out. Try just:

```
< ?php include( 'page1.php' ); ?><br/>
```

Instead.

As to the rest, maybe we can get some clarification. `Page1.php` contains no JS so how can it run the JS as normal when opening it directly? Maybe you can explain what doesn't work normally?

#### Edit

I have a feeling you are referring to the body `onLoad` within your question. If so I have always found JQuery to be a bit weird when put into the HTML directly. Instead you can try and run your JQuery after the DOM itself has loaded by putting this into your `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#divkat").load("page1.php");
    });
</script>
```

And replace the body tag with:

```
<body>
```

Also for the hyperlinks you might wanna look into using JQuery events using the function `on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yogesh I pasted the code like that on purpose to replicate the users own code and post.

Comment: I discover now that < ! - - < ?php include( 'page1.php' ); ?> - - > 
is not necessary. you see that there is a link with onclick function
that load the content between the div's where is the comment.

Comment: @DiegoMartincic Was that the problem that the initial HTML wasn't being loaded?

Comment: This is my post:
I discover now that < ! - - < ?php include( 'page1.php' ); ?> - - > 

is not necessary. you see that there is a link with onclick function
that load the content between the div's where is the comment. 
The content of page1.php is on 
www.istrapano360.com/public_html/main/page1.php

Comment: @DiegoMartincic That page seems ok to me, whats the problem again?

Comment: when I click on the imagine it open in a new tab not in a popup box(shadowbox) what I want.
btw the link will contain a swf file of a virtual tour panorama